# PAYPAL REST API & EURO currency

Tags: paypal

It seems that the latest REST API handle only USD currency (have tried with EUR currency, but got an error "Value is not supported at this time". Using USD works perfectly).

Does anyone knows if it will be available soon or should i go with the previous sdk ?
When i say soon, it's 2/3 months...

ps : I know that it's not a real developer question, but Paypal considers stackoverflow as its [community forum](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/support)...

Updated :
I've tried this [test sample](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/api/#create-a-payment).

If i set :

```
amount.setCurrency("EUR");   // instead of amount.setCurrency("USD");
```

I have this answer :

```
com.paypal.exception.HttpErrorException: Error code : 400 with response :
{
 "name":"VALIDATION_ERROR",
 "details": [ {"field":"transactions[0].amount.currency",
               "issue":"Value is not supported at this time"}
            ],
 "message":"Invalid request - see details",
 "information_link":"https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/#VALIDATION_ERROR",
 "debug_id":"2aeb5d81964ce"
}
```

Comment: What API call or request are you specifically making where you are passing over the currency?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

These API's currently only support USD at this time.  I did check, and there are plans to add additional support for the rest of the currencies, however this is not live yet.

**edit:** As of 07/31, you can use EUR (and other) currencies with our REST API's. They have also been opened up for a lot more countries. See [this page](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/integration/direct/rest_api_payment_country_currency_support/) for more details.

Comment: Ok. New API is much more easier to understand and to implement than the older one... too bad for me ^^.

Comment: EUR (and others) are available now.

Comment: does paypal's rest API not accept BRL yet? I'm getting this same error, but BRL is in that list

Comment: @dietbacon i am trying to use BRL too but same error.. Its already June 2016.. Wont they accept other currencies ?